# Handling form submission in another method

Tags: php, symfony

I want to get submission data in `sendAction()` below but I can't. Examples in documentation are all done in a single method. I'm generating form in `indexAction()` and handling submission in `sendAction()`.

There are many examples on web as well as in Stackowerflow but for some reason there is no example like mine, or maybe I missed.

Thanks for the help

```
namespace Se\HirBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $defaultData = array('message' => 'Type your message here');

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
                ->setAction($this->generateUrl('email_send'))
                ->setMethod('POST')
                ->add('name', 'text')
                ->add('email', 'email')
                ->add('message', 'textarea')
                ->add('send', 'submit')
                ->getForm();

        return $this->render('SeHirBundle:Default:email.html.twig',
                            array('page' => 'Email', 'form' => $form->createView()));
    }

    public function sendAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
        {
            $name = //How to get submission data
            $email = //How to get submission data
            $message = //How to get submission data

            return new Response('Email sent');
        }

        return new Response('Form is faulty');
    }
}
```

This prints nothing as well: `$this->get('request')->request->get('name');`

**When I dump $request, I get this:**

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request Object
(
    [attributes] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object
        (
            [parameters:protected] => Array
                (
                    [_controller] => Se\HirBundle\Controller\EmailController::sendAction
                    [_route] => email_send
                    [_route_params] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [request] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object
        (
            [parameters:protected] => Array
                (
                    [form] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => 11
                            [email] => 11@1.com
                            [message] => Type your message here
                            [send] => 
                            [_token] => NfPK_MN6oWYQm2SRrgRjoldwkrodiT033FNsXSjv3TA
                        )

                )

        )
```

Comment: `$request->get('name')`

Comment: Didn't print anything. No error.

Comment: You can also dump whole $request object and look where it store post values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pull POST data directly from request you can do `$request->request->get('name')`.

Comment: Error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::request()

Comment: Sorry, it isn't a method it's an instance of ParameterBag, fixed the answer.

Comment: Error gone away but no data printed. `echo $request->request->get('name'); exit;`

Comment: Which means there is no 'name' POST parameter. Use debug toolbar to check what is in your request.

Comment: There is, check updated post above please. $request dump shows it.

Comment: It shows you have 'form' parameter and inside it 'name'. There is no 'name' directly in request. To get what you need you should probably run `$request->request->get('form')['name']`.

Comment: Thanks it worked now. I'm learning so it will take time to digest S2.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to create your own form class and use it in both actions. Once for generation and once for validation.

Comment: I've just created an example like that. It is a good way as well.

Comment: It gives you all the options for build in *validation*, *code re-usability* and *protection* like CSRF-protection. That's why you should use it over the suggested solution above. The time spend is low and the benefits are very high :)